# Symfony Mailer - Migrate addPart from SwiftMailer

Tags: symfony, symfony-mailer

I am migrating from SwiftMailer to Symfony Mailer in my application.

How to migrate `addPart` method of SwiftMailer to Symfony Mailer? In my case the content type is `text/plain`

```
->addPart('Plain text content', 'text/plain');
```

using

- swiftmailer 6.1
- symfony mailer 4.4

Comment: Wouldn't `$email->text("...")` do the job? https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-contents Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yeah, in my case (plain text part) it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. For some reason I overlooked this simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the plain text part of your email with Symfony Mailer, you can use

```
$email->text("...")
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-contents for a complete reference

Answer (score 1):

You would just migrate it to

```
->text('Plain text content')
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#message-contents

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$email->from($fromEmail)
->to($toEmail)
->html($html_content)  /// for html content
->text($text_content)  /// for text content 
->replyTo($email_info['reply_email'])
->subject($email_info['subject']);
```

hope this will help. Comment the line if you don't need html content or text content.